# S3 Redirect base domain to key prefix folder

Tags: redirect, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm using an S3 bucket to host a static site `mydomain.com`. Originally the blog content layout was

- index.html
- posts/article.html

Now I keep all the blog content inside a `blog` directory.

- blog/index.html
- blog/posts/article.html

I have enabled website hosting on mydomain.com bucket. I would like to use [S3's custom redirection rules](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/HowDoIWebsiteConfiguration.html) to redirect old urls which lacked the 'blog' prefix. For example, `mydomain.com/index.html` should redirect to `mydomain.com/blog/index.html`.

I've tried

```
<RoutingRules>
    <RoutingRule>
        <Condition>
            <KeyPrefixEquals>/</KeyPrefixEquals>
        </Condition>
        <Redirect>
            <ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>blog/</ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>
        </Redirect>
    </RoutingRule>
</RoutingRules>
```

and

```
<RoutingRules>
    <RoutingRule>
        <Condition>
            <KeyPrefixEquals>mydomain.com/</KeyPrefixEquals>
        </Condition>
        <Redirect>
            <ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>mydomain.com/blog</ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>
        </Redirect>
    </RoutingRule>
</RoutingRules>
```

but the first results in a redirection loop (not surprising) and the second does not work.

Answer (score 4):

Check if following hack works - Add "HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals=404" to the condition.  I am expecting following sequence of events to happen

1. Access "www.example.com/index.html"
2. Gets 404 as page doesn't not exists
3. Your prefix condition along with 404 matches a
   Redirect rule
4. So "/blog" should be added as prefix
5. Returns "www.example.com/blog/index.html" page.

Reading documentation I did not find a way to specify negative condition like "KeyPrefixNotEquals" to avoid the recursion

Comment: This does work to redirect from example.com/index.html to example.com/blog/index.html. One unfortunate drawback though is that the condition can be met any time a 404 page is reached so all 404 pages redirect to urls with redirection loops. You're right, the conditions S3 provides for routing logic are really quite limited without negative conditions - to solve this problem properly, logical operators that allow 0th key checking are needed. May file an issue to that effect. For now, I'm using small files to redirect the couple of blog posts to the new urls, which works for now.

Comment: Yes agreed. If feasible you might have to enumerate all possible prefixes and having one redirect rule per prefix match.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the Redirect Rules and add in the ReplaceKeyPrefixWith item:

```
<RoutingRules>
  <RoutingRule>
     <Redirect>
       <Protocol>https</Protocol>
       <HostName>mydomain.com</HostName>
       <ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>blog/</ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>
       <HttpRedirectCode>301</HttpRedirectCode>
     </Redirect>
  </RoutingRule>
</RoutingRules>
```

NOTE: Some browsers cache can be very sticky so ensure that you either use a different browser session to check your redirect rules or close and reopen the browser to check.

Comment: This also causes a "redirection loop" due to too many redirects. The first redirection is to mydomain.com/blog, which then redirects to mydomain.com/blog/blog, etc until the url is huge.

Comment: Thank you! Just what I was looking for.